# Storing & Retrieving specific columns into a variable of a result set containing single row in a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I need to store the values of a particular column into a separate variable, based on the value stored on different columns.

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `someDB`$$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `GetFeedSetting`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `GetFeedSetting` (IN `feed_setting_user_id` BIGINT) READS SQL DATA DETERMINISTIC SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
   DECLARE noOfHits INT (11);
   SELECT
    `read_setting_status`,
    `write_setting_status`,
    `write_cmt_setting_status`,
    `like_setting_status`
  FROM
    `feed_item_setting`
  WHERE `user_id` = feed_setting_user_id;
 END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

From the above snippet of code, the result retrieved will always be in a single row within a result set.
How should I able to assign variables to these below columns
`read_setting_status`,`write_setting_status`,`write_cmt_setting_status`, and `like_setting_status`

In order to store values in the form of arrays and access it via indexes. How Am I supposed to assign values to separate variables, in order to carry out some further operations based on column names assigned to the variable

Answer (score 2):

You can store Select data like this

```
  DECLARE myread_setting_status DOUBLE;
  SELECT `read_setting_status`, INTO myread_setting_status FROM
    `feed_item_setting`WHERE `user_id` = feed_setting_user_id;;
```

Of course i don't know which type read_setting_status really is, but you should get idea

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by nbk that's the query you should be using. Based on your table structure define the data type **int** or **varchar**

```
DECLARE v_read_setting_status, v_write_setting_status, v_write_cmt_setting_status, v_like_setting_status int or varchar;   #check you structure

SELECT 
    `read_setting_status`,
    `write_setting_status`,
    `write_cmt_setting_status`,
    `like_setting_status`
INTO 
     v_read_setting_status, 
     v_write_setting_status, 
     v_write_cmt_setting_status,
     v_like_setting_status 
FROM 
     `feed_item_setting`
WHERE
    `user_id` = feed_setting_user_id;
```